# Failed to start PersistenceManager in DolphinDB

Tags: database, dolphindb

I execute the following code in  standalone DolphinDB server,

```
n = 1000000;
tableSchema = streamTable(n:0,`hardwareId`ts`temp1,[INT,TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE])
share(tableSchema,"sensorInfoTable")
enableTablePersistence(objByName("sensorInfoTable"), false, false, n)
```

The result shows the following information,

```
To enable table persistence, turn on the persistence manager by specifying the configuration parameter persistenceDir for the publisher node.
```

So I add the following configuration in dolphindb.cfg.

```
persistenceDir="C:\DolphinDB\streamPersistence"
```

But when I run Dolphindb.exe,it terminated abnormally. I found that there is an error showed in dolphindb.log [image: like this]
    I'm sure this directory exists.why did I fail to start PersistenceManager？

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the double quote enclosing the path. DolphinDB doesn't use any double quote for parameter values in configuration file.

```
persistenceDir=C:\DolphinDB\streamPersistence
```